# Runtime error 6 'overflow' where variable declared as integer

Tags: vba, excel

There is a Runtime error 6 'overflow' where variable declared as integer.

```vb
Sub yahoo()
  Dim n As Integer
  Range("A:a").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*yahoo*"
  n = Range("a:a").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
  Range("c1") = n
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [ask] - dumping code asking to *solve* is not how this site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace Integer to Long (more regarding VBA data types at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx)

```
Sub yahoo()
  Dim n As Long
  Range("A:a").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*yahoo*"
  n = Range("a:a").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
  Range("c1") = n
End Sub
```